# How to change Synapse hotkey on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, synapse

I was using Synapse in Ubuntu 13.10 with the hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>. After updating to Ubuntu 14.04 I tried to use the same configuration, but after each reboot the configuration is cleared.

I've checked the file `~/.config/hotkeys/synapse.hotkeys` and seems to be OK:

```
[hotkey:activate]
Owner=synapse
Signature=<Shift><Control>space
```

How can I make the hotkey available after rebooting my PC?

Answer (score 3):

I've also encountered this problem in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and searched exhaustively for this. Finally I found a workaround for this problem.
The way is to use a lightweight tool named `xdotool` to simulate moves and clicks of the mouse, and then assign a shortcut for it. 
The step in detail is as followed:

1. Open a terminal and install `xdotool` via command `sudo apt-get install xdotool`
2. Try figuring out the coordinates of the icon of synapse on top panel. Usually the coordinates of top left on the screen is 0,0 (X, Y). When you type the command `xdotool mousemove 0 0 click 1 mousemove restore` you will probably find the mouse move to the top left and click and then come back to the previous location. Then you can increase X depending on your own. On my computer the coordinates are 950 0 (may differ with resolution/notification area icons but won't vary much).
3. After successfully activating synapse via command line, we try to assign a shortcut for it. Search `Keyboard` via `Dash` and open it. In `Shortcuts`, add a `Custom Shortcuts`. Type the name whatever you like and copy `xdotool mousemove X Y mousemove restore` (X Y for your own) as the command and click `Apply`. Then you'll find it `disabled`. Don't worry, just click `disabled` and it will show `new accelerator..` then type your own short keys on keyboard simultaneously.
4. Close the window and enjoy it :)

Answer (score 2):

I did have the same problem with the version found in the testing-ppa (ppa:synapse-core/testing). However, as stated in this bugreport https://bugs.launchpad.net/synapse-project/+bug/1288839  you can use the saucy salamander package from ubuntu 13.10 (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/+package/synapse) which runs just fine on my ubuntu 14.04 installation.